# Pass file chooser filter between platforms

Tags: java, c#, user-interface

I have a Java application, where all user interactions are made by Swing components (`JOptionPane`/`JFileChooser` etc.).

Currently, I'm working on transforming the application to some sort of server, and pass UI events to different client implementations.

I wrote a `UIImplementer` interface that should be implemented by the UI client:

```
public interface UIImplementer {
    public void info(String message, String title, int options);

    public void warn(String message, String title, int options);

    public void error(String message, String title, int options);

    public boolean confirm(String question, String title, int options);

    public String chooseFile(String InitialAbsPath, String title, String ... exceptableExtentions);
}
```

So far so good, except the `exceptableExtentions` filter in `chooseFile` isn't always sufficient, and some filters in the application are more complicated. I'm working on a C# implementation and am looking for a way to filter the files in the client's side file chooser UI.

I know I could return the selected file to the Java code, run the filter code to see if it fits, and if not, pop up an info message followed by another file chooser, but I think there can be a better way.

What's the best approach to handle file filtering without passing messages back and forth?

Comment: Whas is the question?

Comment: Well, I thought the implicit question is obvious. Anyway, post have been edited.

Comment: You've just repeated your words. Any chance to explain further what is the concrete problem in filtering the files on the client side?

Comment: The concrete problem is that a filter can perform any type of custom operations to filter the files. I was looking for a way to pass some sort of custom filter psaudo code to the client, which in turn can interpret it and use it as a filter. To me it sounds like an imeginary thing, and more important - I'm open for better suggestions. This is why I left the question as is.

Comment: How are the client and server communicating?  What data do they pass to each other?